# Android - How to connect to abstract socket with app

Tags: java, android, unix-socket

I was wondering how can I connect to an abstract socket through and android app. I am really new to this but I have android sdk and ndk installed. Any help would be appreciated.

abstract socket are explained here
 [sockets](http://blog.eduardofleury.com/archives/2007/09/13)

Comment: You might wish to explain in greater detail what you mean by an abstract socket.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided describes abstract sockets as:

> These sockets provide a communication channel between two processes in the same machine

This is generally called inter process communication (IPC). Seeing that Android Apps are executed in a sandbox, they generally can't see much of their environment, other than things that are exposed by the Android API.

Luckily, the Android API provides means to facilitate IPC. Have a look at the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), particularly the part about [`Messenger`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger), which are described as:

> If you need your interface to work across different processes, you can create an interface for the service with a `Messenger`

So, if you only need to perform IPC, this is the Android way to do it; or is there an explicit reason to use the referenced abstract sockets?

Comment: I need it so I can connect to the process and see what kind of input it can take and what it outputs. Since following it's pid to /proc/<pid>/fd/1 has a link to /bin/null